# How to create a debian installer deb package, such that while installing it will prompt license agreement before installing?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, debian, prompt

I created a debian as .deb
While installing as follows:
`sudo apt install ./<mysoftware>.deb`  
it ask administrator password and installed succesfully.

But I want to first flash a license agreement prompt to the user before installing

Please suggest me the way to do the above requirement in Ubuntu22.04

---

I want to initiate this problem's solution.

Comment: Do it in a pre-install script. But careful: if your software is not "free software" you should be sure you do not link (also dynamic link) or include software which incompatible license. Being "free" doesn't mean you can do what you want with it. Debian is not designed for such requirement (but we had similar software in non-free, I think old microsoft fonts, and java were one of them, with a prompt)